# Why i didn't get response after spark job done

Tags: java, apache-spark

In spark UI my job was endded correctly but my application didn't return result , i don't have any java processing after this job.

My application control data type for semi structured files (load csv file + data types from each column, then apply those types to columns)

My test case was with 5M lines, for 1, 2 and 3M it's working correctly

```
public ErrorAccumulationResult controlStructure(Structure struct, String MappingTablesDirectory, String mode, Long packageId) throws IOException, AnalysisException {

System.out.println("==============================| START CONTROL PROCESS |==============================");



JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile(sessionMetaData.getInputPath(), 32);
JavaPairRDD<String, Long> filtredsDataKV = data.zipWithIndex().filter(t -> indexes.contains(t._2 + 1));

JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Long>> partOfDataRdd = sc.parallelize(filtredsDataKV.take(1000));

List<ColumnDateFormat> patternList = partOfDataRdd.map(iterator -> {
    List<ColumnDateFormat> columnDateFormats = new ArrayList<>();
    String row = iterator._1;
    if (!row.equals("")) {
        String[] arr = row.trim().split(Pattern.quote(sep), -1);
        for (int i = 0; i < cols.size(); i++) {
            String type = cols.get(i).getType();
            String name = cols.get(i).getName();
            int index = cols.get(i).getIndex();

            switch (type) {
            case "Date":
                Map<String, Long> count = Common.countPossibleDatePatterns(arr[i]);
                ColumnDateFormat columnDateFormat = new ColumnDateFormat();
                columnDateFormat.setName(name);
                columnDateFormat.setIndex(index);
                columnDateFormat.setPatternsCount(count);
                columnDateFormats.add(columnDateFormat);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return columnDateFormats;
}).reduce((colDate1, colDate2) -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < colDate1.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, Long> count1 = colDate1.get(i).getPatternsCount();
        Map<String, Long> count2 = colDate2.get(i).getPatternsCount();
        Map<String, Long> count = new HashMap<>();
        count1.forEach((pattern, value) -> {
            count.put(pattern, value + count2.get(pattern));
        });
        colDate1.get(i).setPatternsCount(count);
    }
    return colDate1;
});

patternList.forEach(p -> {
    Map<String, Long> count = p.getPatternsCount();
    String pattern = count.entrySet().stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
            .findFirst().get().getKey();
    p.setPattern(pattern);
});


ErrorsAccumulator acc = new ErrorsAccumulator();
ErrorReportingAccumulator accReporting = new ErrorReportingAccumulator();

sc.sc().register(acc);
sc.sc().register(accReporting);

// Paths initialization....


JavaRDD<org.apache.spark.sql.Row> castColumnsToType = filtredsDataKV.mapPartitions(tuple2Iterator -> {

    List<org.apache.spark.sql.Row> results = new ArrayList<>();

    while (tuple2Iterator.hasNext()) {

        String[] rowAfterConverting = new String[cols.size()];

        Tuple2<String, Long> iterator = tuple2Iterator.next();

        String row = iterator._1;
        Long index = iterator._2 + 1;

        if (!row.equals("")) {

            String[] arr = row.trim().split(Pattern.quote(sep), -1);

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < cols.size(); i++) {

                    boolean mandatory = cols.get(i).isMandatory();
                    String type = cols.get(i).getType();
                    String mapTabName = cols.get(i).getMapTabName();
                    String mapColName = cols.get(i).getMapColName();
                    String coe = cols.get(i).getCoe();
                    String decision = cols.get(i).getDecision();
                    String name = cols.get(i).getName();


                    switch (type) {
                        case "Date":
                            if (arr[i].equals("") && mandatory) {
                                acc.add(new Error("Missing value", index, name, arr[i], decision));
                                accReporting.add(struct.getName() + ";" + name + ";" + "Missing value");
                                rowAfterConverting[i] = "";
                            } else {
                                String pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                                for (ColumnDateFormat columnDateFormat : patternList) {
                                    if (columnDateFormat.getIndex() != i) {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    pattern = columnDateFormat.getPattern();
                                }
                                String colConvertedToDate = Common.convertDate(arr[i], pattern);
                                if (colConvertedToDate.equals("null")) {
                                    acc.add(new Error("Data type mismatch", index, name, arr[i], decision));
                                    accReporting.add(struct.getName() + ";" + name + ";" + "Data type mismatch");
                                }
                                rowAfterConverting[i] = colConvertedToDate;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "Decimal":
                            //same for decimal 
                            break;
                        case "Integer":
                             //same for integer 
                            break;
                        default:

                            break;
                    }

                    if (mapTabName != null && mapColName != null && coe != null) {

                       //Other control for user types 
                    }
                }

            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("Element don't exist ! error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("Blank row");
        }

        results.add(RowFactory.create(rowAfterConverting));
    }
    return results.iterator();
});


SparkUtils.csvToParquet(outputFilePathPARQUET, struct, castColumnsToType);

// Accumulation  manipulation 

System.out.println("==============================| DETECTION PROCESS TAKE " + (duration/1000000000) + " |==============================");
return new ErrorAccumulationResult(acc.value(), errorReporting);
```

}

Here's the execution flow for this task :

[image]

there's the logs :

```
2019-09-09 21:16:07,442 284413221 INFO  org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner - Cleaned accumulator 16754
2019-09-09 21:16:07,442 284413221 INFO  org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner - Cleaned accumulator 16765
2019-09-09 21:16:07,442 284413221 INFO  org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner - Cleaned accumulator 16768
2019-09-09 21:16:07,442 284413221 INFO  org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner - Cleaned accumulator 16771
2019-09-09 21:16:07,442 284413221 INFO  org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner - Cleaned accumulator 16753
2019-09-09 21:16:07,442 284413221 INFO  org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner - Cleaned accumulator 16759
2019-09-09 21:16:07,444 284413223 INFO  o.a.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo - Removed broadcast_791_piece4

Spark version : org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Running Spark version 2.3.1
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? could you please elaborate. Or post sample code.

Comment: Hi @Prateek  i added more details, thanks.

Comment: could you please print content of castColumnsToType RDD ?